# Windows 8.1 Process Migration Limits CPU frequency scaling

Tags: performance, cpu, windows-8.1, turbo-boost

**Summary**: I've noticed that with Windows 8.1 on my laptop, running a single CPU intensive program does not cause the CPU frequency to scale to its maximum value.  I suspect that this is because of process migration occurring too quickly.  I'm wondering if there is a solution to this problem or if anyone else has noticed it.

**Details**:

I was running something in VirtualBox and I noticed it was much slower than I expected (a CPU intensive workload that should not have much virtualization overhead).  After investigating I noticed that the host CPU was running at 1.17 GHz instead of its max speed of 2.53 GHz.  Some troubleshooting eventually led me to just run [Prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/freesoft/) torture test with a single thread on the Windows 8.1 host OS (so the rest of my question ignores virtualization).  The result (shown below) was that a single Prime95 thread also left the frequency at 1.17 GHz

[image: low frequency for single thread]

However, if I ran Prime95 with 4 threads then the system would be fully loaded and the frequency boosted up to over 2.5 GHz (it has turbo mode so the exact frequency fluctuated).

[image: 4 threads top frequency]

Furthermore if I set the CPU affinity for the Prime95 process to limit it to a single logical CPU then it also reached its max frequency (around 2.9GHz, higher turbo since the other cores were idle).

[image: 1 thread set to run on a single core]

I also have Linux, and Windows 7, installed on other partitions on this laptop and I tested with those OSes as well.  Neither of them had a problem with a single process boosting to its maximum frequency.  So it seems the problem is something related to how Windows 8.1 interacts with my HP EliteBook 8440p laptop.  The screenshots I showed here were when I tested with Prime95 because that is an application that I know simply stresses the CPU.  But my larger concern is that I experienced the same problem with both VirtualBox and VMware Workstation 7.1.  Any ideas for a possible solution are appreciated.